# Given the root, how to find the ends of a tree/directed acyclic graph based on condition in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

## **Details of my problem:**

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
Child Parent Ownership  Parent_Country
  A     B      0.1      Foreign
  A     C      0.3      Domestic
  A     D      0.6      Domestic
  B     E      0.4      Domestic
  B     F      0.6      Foreign
  H     J       1       Foreign
  C     G      0.9      Foreign
  A     G      0.05     Foreign
  D     H      0.8      Foreign
  D     I      0.2      Domestic
```

Note that the data structure is a tree/DAG structure where A->B->E, A->B->F, etc. A is the ultimate Child owned by multiple parents who are owned by multiple parents.

What I want to do is to output just the Parent(s) that meets the following criteria: 1. Owns 30% of A or more directly and/or indirectly 2. Is foreign. 3. This foreign parent needs to be the first level foreign parent that meets the ownership criteria, and any foreign parent that owns that foreign parent and still meets the ownership criteria does not count

Desired output:

```
{'A':[('G',0.33),('H',0.48)]}
```

Note that in this case the parents that meet this criteria is G and H, because H is foreign and owns 80% of D who owns 60% of A (0.8*0.6=0.48), and G is foreign and owns 90% of C who owns 30% of A, plus G owns 5% of A directly (0.9*0.3+0.05=0.33). Also note, that even though J owns 100% of H so should also own 48% of A, but because H is closer to A, J does not meet the criteria.

## **What I have tried:**

Based on a similar question I asked, I understand that my dataframe represents a weighted directed acyclic graph, where Ultimate Child A is the root. I first created a dict appending all the parents, ownership, and country to each child, but then I'm a bit stuck. I tried using dfs to calculate all the ultimate ownership percentages in A for every parent, and output all the parents of A that fit the criteria. However, I met the following issues:

1. I can't keep only the root A as the key in the output dictionary and append multiple rows containing parents & ownership pairs to A. I tried initializing the key outside of the for loop but got an error
2. I want the loop to break when it hits the first parent that meets the criteria for that path, but for other paths to keep going.
3. Maybe I just need to use a totally different method getting to the end result. Please heelpp

See below the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df=pd.DataFrame({'Child': list('AAABBHCADD'), 'Parent': list('BCDEFJGGHI'), 'Ownership': [.1,.3,.6,.4,.6,1,.9,.05,.8,.2],'Parent_Country':('Foreign','Domestic','Domestic','Domestic','Foreign','Foreign','Foreign','Foreign','Foreign','Domestic')})

#Create a dict appending all the parents to each child
dag_as_dict = defaultdict(list) # {child: list of (parent, weight)}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    dag_as_dict[row['Child']].append((row['Parent'], row['Ownership'],row['Parent_Country']))

#Calculate ultimate ownership in A for every parent
def get_weights_of_descendants(dag_as_dict, root, root_weight=1.0, country='Domestic', result=None,real_parent=None):
    if result is None:
        result = defaultdict(float)
    if real_parent is None:
        real_parent=defaultdict(str)
    for parent, weight, country in dag_as_dict[root]:
        new_weight=weight*root_weight
        result[parent] += new_weight
        if result[parent]>0.3 and country!='Domestic':
            real_parent[root]=parent
            break
        get_weights_of_descendants(dag_as_dict, parent, new_weight, country,result,real_parent)            
    return real_parent
#    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org).

First let's see how to get all ownership without filtering:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.rename(columns={'Ownership': 'weight'}),
                            source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph, edge_attr='weight')


foreign = set(df.loc[df['Parent_Country'].eq('Foreign'), 'Parent'])
# {'B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J'}

paths = {f: sum(np.product([G.get_edge_data(*e)['weight'] for e in p])
                 for p in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(G, f, 'A'))
         for f in foreign
        }
```

Output:

```
{'J': 0.48, 'G': 0.32, 'B': 0.1, 'F': 0.06, 'H': 0.48}
```

Now if you want to only keep those ≥ 30% and not having a foreign parent, you can add a step to remove the parents that own a foreign company and filter based on a threshold:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.rename(columns={'Ownership': 'weight'}),
                            source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph, edge_attr='weight')


foreign = set(df.loc[df['Parent_Country'].eq('Foreign'), 'Parent'])
# {'B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J'}

paths = {f: total
         for f in foreign
         if (total:=
             sum(np.product([G.get_edge_data(*e)['weight'] for e in p])
                 for p in nx.all_simple_edge_paths(G, f, 'A'))
            ) >= 0.3
        }

# remove foreign parents of a foreign company:
for n in list(paths):
    for s in G.predecessors(n):
        if s in paths:
            del paths[s]
```

Output:

```
{'G': 0.32, 'H': 0.48}
```

Graph (red nodes are foreign, edge width proportional to the % ownership):

[image: graph of companies tree]

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Child': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'H', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D'],
                   'Parent': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'J', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
                   'Ownership': [0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0, 0.9, 0.05, 0.8, 0.2],
                   'Parent_Country': ['Foreign', 'Domestic', 'Domestic', 'Domestic', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Domestic']})
```

###### code to plot the graph

This requires [`graphviz`](https://graphviz.org/).

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout, to_agraph

df = pd.DataFrame({'Child': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'H', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D'],
                   'Parent': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'J', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
                   'Ownership': [0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0, 0.9, 0.05, 0.8, 0.2],
                   'Parent_Country': ['Foreign', 'Domestic', 'Domestic', 'Domestic', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Foreign', 'Domestic']})

foreign = set(df.loc[df['Parent_Country'].eq('Foreign'), 'Parent'])
# {'B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J'}

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.rename(columns={'Ownership': 'penwidth'})
                              .assign(label=lambda d: d['penwidth'],
                                      penwidth=lambda d: d['penwidth'].mul(5),
                                     ),
                            source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                            edge_attr=['penwidth', 'label'])

nx.set_node_attributes(G, {n: {'color': 'red'} for n in foreign})

A = to_agraph(G)
A.layout('dot')
A.draw('graph.png')
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway your answer is very clear! I'm just curious about the graph you attached here. It looks like it's hand-drawn. I tried to generate this graph with my real dataset using networkx and it's very messy and the nodes are overlapping each other. I just wonder if you know a way to generate this graph in networkx that looks like yours in a clean way. Thanks!

Comment: No it's generated programmatically. I combined `networkx` and `graphviz`. I don't have the code with me now, but I'll try to remember to add it if you want (remind me if I forget)

Comment: @uggghh I added the code to plot the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach (`networkx` is great):

First build a dictionary (the child-parent relationship) and a set (which contains the foreigners):

```py
parents = {
    child: dict(zip(gdf["Parent"], gdf["Ownership"]))
    for child, gdf in df.groupby("Child")
}
foreign = set(df.loc[df["Parent_Country"].eq("Foreign"), "Parent"])
```

```py
{'A': {'B': 0.1, 'C': 0.3, 'D': 0.6, 'G': 0.05},
 'B': {'E': 0.4, 'F': 0.6},
 'C': {'G': 0.9},
 'D': {'H': 0.8, 'I': 0.2},
 'H': {'J': 1.0}}

{'F', 'H', 'B', 'G', 'J'}
```

Then the actual search:

```py
result = {}
for child, ownership in parents.items():
    stack = [(child, 1.)]
    while stack:
        last_parent, last_own = stack.pop()
        if last_parent not in parents:
            continue
        for parent, own in parents[last_parent].items():
            new_own = last_own * own
            if last_parent != child:
                new_own += ownership.get(parent, 0)
            if parent in foreign and new_own >= 0.3:
                result.setdefault(child, []).append((parent, new_own))
                continue
            stack.append((parent, new_own))
```

Result for the sample:

```py
{'A': [('H', 0.48), ('G', 0.32)],
 'B': [('F', 0.6)],
 'C': [('G', 0.9)],
 'D': [('H', 0.8)],
 'H': [('J', 1.0)]}
```

Same approach as a recursive function:

```py
def get_parents(child, last_own=1., ownership=None, level=0):
    if child not in parents:
        return []
    if ownership is None:
        ownership = parents[child]
    result = []
    for parent, own in parents[child].items():
        new_own = last_own * own
        if level > 0:
            new_own += ownership.get(parent, 0)
        if parent in foreign and new_own >= 0.3:
            result.append((parent, new_own))
            continue
        result.extend(get_parents(parent, new_own, ownership, level + 1))
    return result
```

Some explanations:

- Variables: The variable `last_own` keeps track of the cummulative ownership (it starts with 1.0 because the accumulation is mainly multiplicative). `ownership` and `level` are for making sure that the *direct* ownership is accounted for: `ownership` contains the information about the direct ownership. `level` (the depth of the recursion) is an auxiliary variable, that to avoid double counting the direct ownership in the *first* step.
- The first `if`-condition makes sure the recursion stops once a node has no childs (the end of a branch).
- The recursion (going one step deeper into the tree): Go over all the childs of the current node: First adjust the cummulative ownership. Then check if the new node is foreign and the cummulative ownership meets the threshold requirement: If so, add it to the result list and skip the last part of the `for`-loop (`continue`). If not, go one step further in the recursion with adjusted parameters (`new_own` and `level`). The recursion has no check if the the new nodes have already been visited because the graph is a directed tree.

Result for `get_parents("A")` is `[('G', 0.32), ('H', 0.48)]`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer not using the networkx package! Sorry it took me a while to reply because I was having trouble understanding your code. First of all, after I applied this code to my dataset which has more levels of ownerships and I got a duplicate parent. The result looked like `('G',0.32), ('G',0.32), ('H',0.48)`. I feel like you already removed duplicates at the beginning so not sure why I still got that result.

Comment: Secondly, can you help explain a bit more the steps you took to come up with the recursive function? E.g. Which line of code is used to remove the other qualified foreign parents of the first qualified foreign parent? Thank you!

Comment: @uggghh Thanks for the feedback. I've added some explanations to the recursive solution and hope they help. Regarding the duplicate: That is strange? I have assumed the graph is a directed tree and in such that shouldn't happen -- have I misunderstood? Remark regarding `networkx`: I don't want to compete with this fantastic library, which I myself use frequently. But I usually find it helpful to see some direct algorithm.